# RShiny text in plot updating, but not data

Tags: r, user-interface, ggplot2, shiny

I have tried many data structure permutations to try to get the data updating in the plot (e.g., subset, preset matrices)

*names(datar):*

```
"Sex" "Age" "Year" "PercViewing.DIVORCED" "PercViewing.MARRIED" "PercViewing.NEVER MARRIED"
```

The desired plot is generated when run alone with input$select identified. However, input$select appears not to be passed from ui to the server script as written (below).

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
   headerPanel("Have you seen an X-rated movie\nin the last year?"),
    sidebarLayout( 
      sidebarPanel(selectInput("select","Select marital status to view",paste(choices=names(datar[4:6])))),
      mainPanel(img(src="liberos.jpg", height = 200, width = 200),h2("Title here",align = "center"),plotOutput("densPlot"))
      )
    )
  )
```

**server.r**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
data<-read.table("/Users/nicole/Dropbox/Shiny/xmoviePerc.csv", sep=",",stringsAsFactors =FALSE
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$densPlot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(datar, aes(x=input$select,fill=datar$Sex)) + 
    geom_density(alpha = 0.5,colour=c("yellow")) +
    labs(title = "Percent who reported viewing\nsex films") +
    ylab("Response density") +
    xlab("Percent who report having viewed") +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(family="Times", face="bold",colour="darkred", size=rel(1.3))) +
    geom_text(data = NULL, x = 20, y = .015, label = input$select,aes(label=text,family="Times")) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Gender reported") +
    theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=16, face="bold"))
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`aes_string()`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/aes_string.html) instead in your `ggplot()` call in `server.r`. `aes()` uses non-standard evaluation, and so it can't understand the text string that `input$select` evaluates to.